# What should be the regex to match the start of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like and I want to match just the first '{' of every `{{xxxx}}` pattern

**{**{abcd}}**{**{efg}}**{**{hij}}

**{**{abcd}}**{**{efg}}**{**{hij}}**{**

I tried with `/(\s|^|.){/g` but this pattern matches

**{**{abcd}**}{**{efg}**}{**{hij}}

Can some one guide me in the right direction

Comment: So, you want to avoid matching `{{{text}}` at all?

Comment: yeah, just the first '{' of every  {{text}}

Comment: Are you removing or replacing? I think you need `/([^{]|^){(?={.*?}})/g` (or `([^{]|^){(?={(?!{).*?}})`), but the final solution depends on what you need to achieve in the end. With JS regex, it often does not matter what the regex matches, but what it *captures* and *how* the regex is used.

Comment: what is the logical benefit of matching each leftmost curly brace ?

Comment: I don't have any clue what you need - why should the last `{` in `{{abcd}}{{efg}}{{hij}}{` be matched?

Comment: I am trying to popup suggestions wherever user has entered a patter {{text}} or intend to when he types {.

Comment: Are you *replacing* text? It looks as if all you need is `/{$/` pattern to match the last `{`. Or even just test for the `{` char on the input event without any regex.

Comment: No, I want to get the index wherever this pattern occurs for which I am using regex.exec, and then using matchedArray.index

Comment: I think now, that you need `/(^|[^{]){/g` and if you need to collect `{` indices, just check if Group 1 matched, and if yes, increment `match.index`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`/(^|[^{]){/g`](https://regex101.com/r/CuDKc9/1) (that matches and captures into Group 1 start-of-string or any char other than `{`, and then matches a `{`) and check if Group 1 matched at each `RegExp#exec` iteration. Then, if Group 1 matched, increment the match index:

```js
var re = /(^|[^{]){/g;
var str = "{{abcd}}{{efg}}{{hij}}\n{{abcd}}{{efg}}{{hij}}{";
//         0       8      15       23      31     38     45
var m, indices = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    indices.push(m.index + (m[1] ? 1 : 0));
}
console.log(indices);
```